OSError When Saving Barcode in Roaming Folder After Converting Python Script to Executable on Windows
I'm having trouble saving a barcode image to the Roaming folder when I convert my Python script to an executable using PyInstaller on Windows. The script works fine during development, but after conversion, I encounter the following error when attempting to save the barcode.
This is my code:
    from barcode import get_barcode_class
    from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
    print(f'Existency: {PRUEBABARCODEPATH} and save in: {PRUEBABARCODESAVEFILE}')
    hr = get_barcode_class('ean8')
    barcode = hr('00000000', writer=ImageWriter())
    filename = barcode.save(PRUEBABARCODESAVEFILE)
    print(f'Filename: {filename}')

This message appears:
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1968, in __call__
> 
>   File "toplevels\configuracion\gui_boletoTTK.py", line 175, in
> Probar_Button_Fun
>     ComandosImpresion(*tuplaApasar, actividad='demo', ventana=self.thisWindow)
> 
>   File "comandosTicket.py", line 55, in __init__
>     objImpresionWindows.Probar_Print_Ticket(ventana)
> 
>   File "comandosTicket.py", line 185, in Probar_Print_Ticket
> 
>     filename = barcode.save(PRUEBABARCODESAVEFILE)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "barcode\base.py", line 64, in save
> 
>   File "barcode\ean.py", line 126, in render
> 
>   File "barcode\base.py", line 100, in render
> 
>   File "barcode\writer.py", line 269, in render
> 
>   File "barcode\writer.py", line 440, in _paint_text
> 
>   File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 834, in truetype
> 
>   File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 831, in freetype
> 
>   File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 257, in __init__
> 
> OSError: cannot open resource

When I test the script while I'm developing it, it doesn't throw an error, but when I convert it to exe as I said this exception appears. So it doesn't create the image in the Roamaing directory.
I am using the barcode library to generate barcodes and Pillow for image manipulation.
The error occurs only after converting the script to an executable with auto-py-to-exe.
The script works correctly in a development environment when run directly with Python.

The error has nothing to do with saving your barcode - the code never gets to that point.  It's failing during the attempt to load the DejaVuSansMono font, needed to generate the barcode image.  Presumably there's some way to get auto-py-to-exe to include the font file in your executable; you may need to add a font_path= parameter to the .save() call, to let the barcode library know where it is.  Or you could add font_size=0, to eliminate the human-readable text in the barcode image - hopefully that avoids the need to load the font file at all.

Could you type an example please?

It appears:
File "D:\josea\José_Andrés\Programación\Pyhton\Codigos\VerificadorEstacionamiento\venv\Lib\site-packages\defusedxml\ElementTree.py", line 12, in 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 2080, in 
from _elementtree import *
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy'
